# port forwarding/network settings preventing from game hosting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista

I asked where to post this question on stackoverflow meta and they directed me here.

Im on wireless connection and I want to host games in [StarCraft: Brood War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft:_Brood_War) and i've been looking everywhere on how to accomplish that.

My internet is amazingly fast so its not an internet problem (and when i play other peoples games dont experience lag)

I found out that i need to have a static IP but I have already checked that i do (i downloaded a program to make my id static and it already was; The program asked for which router I used So i think it checked the router settings already)

I found out that i need to allow Sc access through the firewall which i already did (i have zone-alarm but I allowed it everything possible except receiving emails lol)

I have recently noticed that few people actually can join my games but most of them cannot. I dont know whats going on here. I really want to be able to host games overall how do I go about checking what is wrong with the network.

**Update:**

Alright I figured out what i did wrong in the first part I did not actually set up forwarding on the router -.- I have tried to fix my mistake. I went to forwarding options in my router (as [this guide](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Netgear/WNR2000/Starcraft.htm) for my specific router suggests) but when i click ok I get a message incorrect ip address.   192.168.1.1 is my routers address. 
The default address that appears there is 192.168.1 (blank) I have set it to my computers current Ip4 adress which 192.168.1.23 I hope this works If so i will post it as an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has worked all i needed to do is to fallow the forwarding guide for my router.
Forwarding guides can be found [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/)

in the end i did have a problem which guide did not answer.
The default ip in the router was 192.168.1 (blank) but i needed to set it to my computers IP in order to get it working. You have to go start and run cmd (just type cmd in search on vista and windows 7) 
Then type in ipconfig and hit enter there is going to be a list IPv4 or IPv6 on that list is your computers IP number type that into the routers settings instead of the default one If the default one doesnt work for you either. 
And it should work from then on.

Comment: yup, you need to forward a port or some ports to a specific machine. your router cannot know which one on your network that would be. also be aware that those 192.x.x.x IPs are your internal ones, your friends need the external one to connect to. Ah yes and of course: Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you mean static IP-address?

I think you might benefit from spending approx. half an hour learning network basics, then this all would be much easier. No offense meant at all!

The basic principle in general is:

- set up a port forwarding on your router, so the requests to your external IP on the port(s) for the game server get directed to the machine you host it on.
- either each time tell your friends your current external IP (if that is dynamic) or just once if you really have a static external IP.
- for dynamic IPs there are services like DynDNS so you can associate a fixed name with your current IP.
- open up the firewall on the machine that hosts the game server, so the ports for the game are allowed in etc.

Then your mates should be able to connect.